# Added more content to tackle the issue: VBA controlling HTML table with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, excel, vba

Background:
Currently we have a situation where we need to fill in three different web based time tracking tools separately which is quite irritating and causes some accuracy problems.

I have created a simple excel app to track time and every week i will submit reports from this app. Two platforms are simple HTML table and it was pretty easy to make submission work with those.

The third webpage uses quite a lot of javascript and with that one i am having problems. I have virtually zero experience working with javascript so i am a bit lost where to find a solution.

Problem:
I can access and insert values to this table using table innerHTML

However when i click update button or click away from the table, all the values disappear. When i physically click a row in the table it highlights it so I am guessing that it is provoking for some javascript function to record changes, am i on the right tracks here?

Unfortunately the site is using login credentials so cannot share it.

I really appreciate any help i can get on tackling this problem!

**EDIT:** It has been a while since i last had a chance to work with this. Current status is that i am still not able to populate report in a way that values would stick after refreshing the page.

After some inspection i found that when you select something from the dropdown category it is calling XMLHttpRequest called UpdateTimesheet.

Some progress at least, if i input value manually and then run following line in VBA it will save the input. Just cannot figure out how to input values to table so that it would actually stick...

```
IE.Document.parentWindow.execScript "TimesheetPage.updateTimesheet()", "Ja
vaScript"
```

After some inspecting i found that the webpage is using MicrosoftAjax and the other thing is that when I click a cell in the table it activates:

Tried xml request but since the site uses autologin with corporate credentials, cannot really ask users to save their credentials.. Not sure if there is a possibility to somehow open explorer first as it will auto login and the use it to fetch requests? Another thing i inspected was IGAikidoCOmpined.js and it pretty long action so don't want to paste whole code as it would be too much. However i guess this part might be interesting,

```
this._set_value($IG.GridActivationProps.ActiveGroupedRow, f);
if (c) {
    this.__raiseClientEvent("ActiveCellChanged", $IG.ActiveCellChangedEventArgs, [this, this.get_activeCell(), true, (k ? k.get_row() : null)])
```

Couldn't figure out yet how to use this script though..

This is the form from the site.

```
<form name="aspnetForm" method="post" action="./TimesheetPage.aspx" id="aspnetForm">
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" id="__EVENTTARGET" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" id="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE"
```

Here is the Table I am trying to fill in:

```
<div id="x:1502727720.3:mkr:container" style="overflow: hidden; height: 372px;" mkr="container">
   <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="table-layout: fixed; width: 861px; visibility: visible;" id="x:1502727720.4:mkr:dataTbl.hdn" mkr="dataTbl.hdn">
      <tbody id="x:1502727720.5:mkr:rows:nw:1" class="ig_TimesheetItem igg_TimesheetItem" nw="1" mkr="rows">
         <tr id="x:-33.10000:adr:0" adr="0" type="row" class="">
            <td adr="0" idx="0" type="cell" wlkd="1" class="" title="" style="width: 275px; text-align: left;"></td>
            <td adr="1" idx="1" type="cell" wlkd="1" class="" style="width: 16px;"><input style="BORDER-RIGHT-WIDTH: 0px; WIDTH: 16px; BORDER-TOP-WIDTH: 0px; BORDER-BOTTOM-WIDTH: 0px; HEIGHT: 16px; VISIBILITY: hidden; BORDER-LEFT-WIDTH: 0px" id="Image" onclick="return false;" src="../images/arrow_right_myTE_disabled.png" alt="Replicate" type="image" name="Image"></td>
            <td adr="2" idx="2" type="cell" wlkd="1" class="" style="width: 40px;"></td>
            <td adr="3" idx="3" type="cell" wlkd="1" class="" style="width: 40px;"></td>
```

Once I activate a row by clicking in any cell of that table, this:

```
<tr id="x:-33.10000:adr:0" adr="0" type="row" class="">
   <td adr="0" idx="0" type="cell" wlkd="1" class="" title="" style="width: 275px; text-align: left;"></td>
   <td adr="1" idx="1" type="cell" wlkd="1" class="" style="width: 16px;"><input style="BORDER-RIGHT-WIDTH: 0px;
```

Becomes this:

```
<tr id="x:-33.10000:adr:0" adr="0" type="row" class="igg_TimesheetActiveRow">
   <td adr="0" idx="0" type="cell" wlkd="1" class="igg_TimesheetActiveCell" title="" tabindex="0" style="width: 275px; text-align: left;"></td>
```

I guess it should be possible to somehow send class to activate certain row?

I found these two functions that seems to be related to activating the edition of the cells they are part of TimesheetPage.aspx

```
Sys.Application.add_init(function() {
    $create(Infragistics.Web.UI.WebDataGrid, {
        "clientbindingprops": [

                                ["CellEditing"], {
                                    "c": {
                                        "ecc": "igg_TimesheetEditCell"

                                'Assignment': [
                                    [], {
                                        "c": {
                                            "ro": false,
                                            "ck": "Assignment",
                                            "eid": "wdgTimeEntry_Assignment"
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }],
                            ["ExitedEditMode:TimesheetPage.timeEntryGridExitingEditMode", "EnteringEditMode:TimesheetPage.timeEntryGridEnteringEditMode"]
                        ]
                    ], , ["CellValueChanged:TimesheetPage.timeEntryGridCellValueChanged", "CellValueChanging:TimesheetPage.timeEntryGridCellValueChanging", "RowAdding::2", "RowsDeleting::2"]
                ],

                        ["Activation", , ], {
                            "c": {
                                "arc": "igg_TimesheetActiveRow",
                                "acc": "igg_TimesheetActiveCell",
                                "arsc": "igg_TimesheetActiveRowSelector",
                                "arsi": "igg_TimesheetActiveRowSelectorImage",
                                "ahc": "igg_TimesheetActiveColumn"

                        ["Selection", 1, , 2, , , , ], {
                            "c": {
                                "sh": "igg_TimesheetSelectedHeader",
                                "ehs": false,
                                "si": "igg_TimesheetSelectedRowSelectorImage",
                                "sr": "igg_TimesheetSelectedRowSelector",
                                "sc": "ig_TimesheetSelected igg_TimesheetSelectedCell"

                    ], , , ["RowSelectionChanging:TimesheetPage.cancelSelectionIfNeeded"]

            ["DataBound:TimesheetPage.timeEntryGridDataBound", "KeyDown:isValidTime", "Initialize:TimesheetPage.timeEntryGridInitialize"],

        "id": "ctl00_ctl00_MainContentPlaceHolder_ContentPlaceHolder_TimeReport_wdgTimeEntry",
        "name": "wdgTimeEntry"
    }, null, null, $get("ctl00_ctl00_MainContentPlaceHolder_ContentPlaceHolder_TimeReport_wdgTimeEntry"));
});


Sys.Application.add_init(function() {
    $create(Infragistics.Web.UI.WebDataGrid, {
        "clientbindingprops": [
            [
                [, 0, 0, 0], {
                    "c": {
                        "vscb": 1,
                        "cbc": 0,
                        "ecr": true,

                        "uid": "ctl00$ctl00$MainContentPlaceHolder$ContentPlaceHolder_TimeReport$wdgTimeCategory",
                        "ti": 0

                        ["EditingCore"]

                                ["CellEditing"], {
                                    "c": {
                                        "ecc": "igg_TimesheetEditCell"

                            ["ExitedEditMode:TimesheetPage.timeCategoryGridExitingEditMode", "EnteringEditMode:TimesheetPage.timeCategoryGridEnteringEditMode"]
                        ]
                    ], , ["CellValueChanged:TimesheetPage.timeEntryGridCellValueChanged", "CellValueChanging:TimesheetPage.timeCategoryGridCellValueChanging", "RowAdding::2", "RowsDeleting::2"]

                        ["Activation", , ], {
                            "c": {
                                "arc": "igg_TimesheetActiveRow",
                                "acc": "igg_TimesheetActiveCell",
                                "arsc": "igg_TimesheetActiveRowSelector",
                                "arsi": "igg_TimesheetActiveRowSelectorImage",
                                "ahc": "igg_TimesheetActiveColumn"


            ["DataBound:TimesheetPage.timeCategoryGridDataBound"],
            []
        ],
        "id": "ctl00_ctl00_MainContentPlaceHolder_ContentPlaceHolder_TimeReport_wdgTimeCategory",
        "name": "wdgTimeCategory"
    }, null, null, $get("ctl00_ctl00_MainContentPlaceHolder_ContentPlaceHolder_TimeReport_wdgTimeCategory"));
});
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you are working with, or provide a jsfiddle example of the problem?

Comment: Perhaps browser automation would help you. e.g. Selenium

Comment: The page may need an event to fire to update the cells. You can use FireBug to see which events are being called. To fire an onChange event you can try something like: Element.FireEvent("OnChange") or Browser.document.parentWindow.ExecScript("$('#MyEleID').change()") using jQuery.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on Firebug Ryan. If i look at the console when inputting hours, it is showing me this event: **unreachable code after return statement[Learn More]  IGAikidoCombined.js:3:4279**

Comment: Some new info added. Website is using ajax so probably I need to try HTTP requests to make it work. The other option would be to go with selenium, although this app should be distributed to people with zero knowledge so I would prefer a method where user doesn't have to install anything..